# path_prefix for asp.net mvc routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) article about how you can prefix routes in ruby on rails. I want to be able to do the same thing with asp.net mvc

So I want to be able to define a route like :

```
/photographers/1/photos/2   //photo 2 of photographer with id 1
/photographers/1/photos     //all of photographer with id 1
```

Any tips ?

**EDIT:**

*"photographers/{id}/photos/{photoID}"* - seems to do the job quite ok, BUT how can I support

```
RedirectToAction<PhotosController>(x => x.Add());
```

I would like to redirect to : /photographers/1/photos/add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Photographers",
    "photographers/{id}/photos/{photoID}",
    new { controller = "Photographers", action = "Photo", photoID = null });
```

Then define your controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Photo(int id, int? photoID)
{
    // If photoID is not null, show just that photo.
    // Otherwise, show all photographs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regex routing](http://iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) or use [wildcards in your routing table](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/27/asp-net-mvc-preview-3-release.aspx) so that the {id*} matches the `/1/photos/2` for the photographers default controller, parse the string, and redirect to an appropriate action.

Also take a look at [this](http://blog.enginefour.com/blog/post/Nested-Resources-In-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) post about nested resources.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
        new Route { Url = "events/[eventId]/tickets/[action]/[id]", 
                    Defaults = new { controller = "Tickets", 
                                     action = "List", id = (string)null }, 
                    RouteHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler) });
```